# Adding a custom query to the model

Tags: php, cakephp

For simplicity's sake, I have two tables: projects and tasks. A project can have many tasks, and a task belongs to a project.
I've set up the database, created the associations and used cake bake to generate the models, controllers and views and all is perfect.
When I look at a the index view for projects, I see a table listing all the projects as expected. What I want to do is really simple: I want a column in that table that shows a count of all the tasks assigned to that project.

The SQL query for this is trivial (returning a list of project names and a count of the tasks):

```
SELECT projects.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE project_id = projects.id) as taskCount
FROM projects
```

So how do I achieve this in CakePHP?
The index method in the projects controller looks like this at the moment:

```
function index() {
    $this->Project->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('projects', $this->paginate());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1608/Virtual-fields) or [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1057/Model-Attributes#counterCache-Cache-your-count-1033), but it is another way.

Comment: Added this to the project model:
    var $virtualFields = array ( 'taskcount' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE project_id = Project.id');
and all is good!